# Elasticsearch fuzzy query

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I am trying to make fuzzy search that should be intended like this

[image: fuzzy search homo sapiens]

And I have my index like this

```
{
  "test": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "last_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "routing": {
          "allocation": {
            "include": {
              "_tier_preference": "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "provided_name": "test",
        "creation_date": "1617623285742",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "MxSWoxSoS6y6x5Jdt2AvMQ",
        "version": {
          "created": "7120099"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Inside that index there is one data with

```
{
  "first_name": "homo sapiens",
  "last_name": "moho"
}
```

I tried to query like this but it doesn't work

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "first_name": {
                "query": "hosan",
                "fuzziness": "AUTO:0,0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but if I search with "hoom", "homoo" or "homos" it works.

Can someone help me with this fuzzy search? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With a query term consisting of 5 characters, (hosan), a fuzziness value of `auto` will only give you an edit distance value of 1, which is not going to be enough to get you from hosan to homo. The max edit distance value you can achieve with `auto` is 2, and you will only achieve that if your query term is greater than 5 characters. You can force a fuzziness value of 3 or 4 to attempt to achieve your desired results, but the reason the ES default is max of 2 is because higher numbers can start yielding unexpected and unwieldy results. Note also that your other search examples (hoom, homoo, etc) are matching only on the word homo. Match queries are OR queries by default, and will return results for any matched term.

Just for reference, `auto` will give you 0 edit distance for query terms of length 1-2 characters, 1 edit distance for query term of 3-5 characters, and 2 edit distance for query terms greater than 5 characters.

So I would bump up your fuzziness value by 1 until you get the result returned when searching on hosan, but only to prove out what I’m outlining here. I personally would not go above a fuzziness value of 2, maybe 3, in any production environment.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research about elasticsearch and fuzzy search, I found that it is imposible to only use fuzzy to expect the result like "homo sapiens" with search keyword "hosan". Then to solve this I need to combine fuzzy with regex query from elasticsearch

Comment: So, what is your final query looks like?